# Checking whether all my classes have the Serializable attribute

Tags: c#

In my current software I make use of serialization and therefore need everything to be marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Is there an easy way of checking this using my Visual Studio without going through them one at a time, or just waiting for it to crash?

To clarify, I don't need to know how to check if a class is serializable in code. I'm talking about using the IDE.

Comment: You can write an unit test for that

Comment: Can't you try and serialize all of them and see if that works? Like a unit test as suggested by @VsevolodGoloviznin

Comment: I have a large number of classes and each time I add a new batch I worry that I forgot one. I wonder if I can use reflection to get all classes in the namespace...

Comment: If you cannot *instantly* find your serializable classes back then you are doing it wrong.  It is the kind of wrong-ness that it really going to hurt you when you need to maintain this code and make changes to any of these classes.  And discover the Hard Way that such a change makes old data unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use reflection to find classes not marked `[Serializable]` you can use reflection to get the class types via [GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes);k(GetTypes);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) and then find only those not marked with [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Serializable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).
try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReflectOnSerializableAttr
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //use Linq
            var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                    where t.IsClass &&  ((t.Attributes & TypeAttributes.Serializable) != TypeAttributes.Serializable)
                    select t;
            q.ToList().ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Name));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class TestSerializableOne
    {
        public string SomeFunc() { return "somefunc"; }
    }

    public class TestForgotSerializable
    {
        private int _testInt = 200;
    }
}
```

The above program outputs:

```
Program
TestForgotSerializable
```